# How to match any Array in EasyMock

Tags: scala, easymock, scalatest

At the moment I have following code:

```
val mockXmlRpc = mock[XmlRpcClient]
mockXmlRpc.execute("foo.",Array[Object]()).andReturn("").anyTimes()
```

During the test execute methid is called few times with different String arrays and I just need to return empty String to all of these calls.

How can I achieve this without writing custom matchers for each call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is a solution to this lurking in EasyMock [documentation](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.2/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#isA%28java.lang.Class%29)

```
mockXmlRpc.execute("foo.", isA(classOf[Array[Object]])).andReturn("").anyTimes()
```

Comment: I keep getting punted back to this old page although EasyMock is on 3.5 now and 'classOf' isn't available anymore.  Does anyone have an updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

For a String array, do this:

```
mockXmlRpc.execute("foo.", EasyMock.anyObject(String[].class)).andReturn(someMockObj);
```